# Beginner question SageMath: maximum-minimum identity

Tags: sagemath

I am a complete beginner to SageMath. I was wondering how I could recreate the [maximum-minimum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-minimums_identity) using it. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "recreate"? Do you want to write some code that takes a list of numbers and calculates the max (or min) in both ways, so you can verify they are indeed equal?

Comment: I would like a system that given the inputs $x_2, \dots, x_N$ gives the whole expansion for max and for min.

Comment: Does that mean to calculate the minimum and maximum using the max-min-identity?  Something like, `def mymax(x): return sum([min(comb)*(-1)^(len(comb)+1) for comb in Combinations(x) if comb])` and `def mymin(x): return sum([max(comb)*(-1)^(len(comb)+1) for comb in Combinations(x) if comb])`?  Or are you looking for a symbolic expansion?

Comment: I am looking for a symbolic expantion, where I can then impose condition. But I have no idea whether this is possible in Sage. I think it might be possible in Mathematica.